# ¿Cómo contar el total de registros de tablas diferentes por separado?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaria saber como puedo contar el total de registros por el Id y ponerlo en una columna por separado e igual con la tabla de materiales...en total serian 5 columas
He probado con Count(*) pero sigo sin poder lograrlo
En la columna Libros deberia quedar algo asi : Total Libros :  30

```
CREATE VIEW V_LIBROMATERIALES AS
SELECT IDUnicoLib as IDUNICO,NumInscripcionLibro AS IDENTIFICACION,TituloLibro AS NOMBRE
from libros 
union all 
select IDUnicoMat AS IDUNICO ,IDMaterial,NombreMaterial
from Materiales
```

Comment: El campo IDUNICO, se supone que sería el que querrías contar, por lo que veo en tabla, pero la identificación de si es libro o materiales, de que campo la sacarías?

Comment: La identificación para libros seria NumInscripcionLibro y para materiales seria IDMaterial. El IDUNICO de libro y materiales es un uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo te faltaría añadir una columna más que tendría una constante como valor que indicaría si es un libro o un material:

```
CREATE VIEW V_LIBROMATERIALES AS
SELECT IDUnicoLib AD IDUnico, 'Libro' AS Tipo, 
       NumInscripcionLibro AS Identificacion, TituloLibro AS Nombre 
FROM   libros 
UNION ALL
SELECT IDUnicoMat AS IDUnico, 'Material' AS Tipo, 
       IDMaterial AS Identificacion, NombreMaterial AS Nombre
FROM   Materiales
```

Entonces para saber el número de libros, ya sólo tendrías que contar el número de filas que tienen el Tipo con valor 'Libro':

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V_LIBROMATERIALES WHERE Tipo = 'Libro';
```

Answer (score 0):

Probaste de esta manera? :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) IDUnicoMat AS IDUNICO,IDMaterial,NombreMaterial FROM Materiales;
```

Debería retornarte la cantidad de registros de esa tabla

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido, creo que la vista debes cambiarla tambien.

```
CREATE VIEW V_LIBROMATERIALES AS
SELECT IDUnicoLib as IDUNICO,NumInscripcionLibro AS IDENTIFICACION,TituloLibro AS NOMBRE
from libros 
union all 
select IDUnicoMat AS IDUNICO ,IDMaterial AS IDENTIFICACION,NombreMaterial
from Materiales
```

Al renombrar el campo IDMaterial como IDENTIFICACION, podrás hacer la consulta sobre la vista sin problemas

```
SELECT IDENTIFICACION, COUNT(IDUNICO) FROM V_LIBROMATERIALES GROUP BY IDENTIFICACION
```